# VBA: Create Outlook All Day Event Appointment

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I'm trying to export a table in Excel to create all day event in Outlook with given subject, start date, end date. Here's what I have:

```
With olAppt
    .AllDayEvent = True
    .Start = "7/29/2015"
    .End = "7/29/2015"
    .Subject = "All Day Event"
    .Save
End With
```

What I get is an event that reads "12:00am All Day Event" and it is placed as a 12:00am event instead of an all day event on the UI of the calendar (the event should not have the 12:00am time attached in front of the subject name but for some reason it is). If I click into the event detail it does have the all day event checkbox checked, and start end time being both 12:00 AM.

I don't want to have to scroll up to see a 12:00am event in the UI but rather a event at the top for where all day event supposed to be placed.

Anyone encountered this issue before? Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff184629.aspx:

> To make the appointment an all-day event, you must set the Start property to 12:00 A.M. (midnight) on the day you want the event to begin, and set End property to 12:00 A.M. on the day after you want the event to end. If you set the Start or End time to a date and time value other than 12:00 A.M., the appointment will become a multiday appointment instead of an all-day event. For example, if your event duration is only one day, set the Start property to 12:00 A.M. on the day you want the event to begin, and set the End property to 12:00 A.M. on the following day. You should always set the End property to 12:00 A.M. on a date that is more than one day after the start date.

Comment: Also, you should "set the AllDayEvent property of the AppointmentItem object to true" ([same source as the answer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862177.aspx)).